# Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH gives different results on two different devices

Tags: android, calendar

I have two devices HTC with android 2.3.5  and Samsung with 2.3.6
now the problem i am facing is
i need the date's week of month.

So i've written this code and installed on both the phones. and set the system date as

> 27th Jan 2013

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  int weekOfMonth =  calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
  Log.i(TAG,"weekOfMonth = "+weekOfMonth);
```

now on HTC the output is

```
 weekOfMonth = 5
```

while on samsung running the same code produces

```
 weekOfMonth = 4
```

this really is screwing my logic n calculations ahead.

am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Where is the code where you have set the system date? That's the most important piece of code here. More importantly, are you running exactly the same code or is there room for differences?

Comment: I believe calendar is locale and timezone dependent. Are your two devices registered to different timezones or locales? If the time is set in terms of milliseconds then it's possible the timezone makes it a different day. When in doubt use JodaTime though http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: One device may also have Monday as the start of the week, since the 27th is a Sunday.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is probably due to Locales. In Java

```
        Calendar calFr = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"), Locale.FRANCE);
        Calendar calUs = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"), Locale.US);
        Calendar calUk = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"), Locale.UK);
        calFr.set(2013, Calendar.JANUARY, 27);
        calUs.set(2013, Calendar.JANUARY, 27);
        calUk.set(2013, Calendar.JANUARY, 27);

        int weekOfMonthFr = calFr.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        int weekOfMonthUs = calUs.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        int weekOfMonthUk = calUk.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println("France week of month is " + weekOfMonthFr);
        System.out.println("USA week of month is " + weekOfMonthUs);
        System.out.println("UK week of month is " + weekOfMonthUk);
```

will give you

```
France week of month is 4
USA week of month is 5
UK week of month is 4
```

Comment: Solved with this code thanks...

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(),Locale.US);
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);

Comment: Thanks Man. you saved my life... :)

Answer (score -1):

Double check the year that it is set to, if one is set to 2012 and the other 2013, that would explain the difference.

Can you get the applications to log the date held in the calendar object and post it here as well just to make sure they have correct information.