# Why are there different time outputs on different Android devices?

Tags: java, android, time, sharedpreferences, android-timepicker

I am writing an Android app that alerts you at a certain time everyday. I am using an Alarm to do this, with a TimePicker in the Preferences activity. On Genymotion, the time on the TimePicker outputs as UTC (epoch) time, but then on my Galaxy s3, the time outputs as a negative.

Here is the TimePicker class:

```
package com.maxmarksstudios.dialywomensselfdefense;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import com.maxmarksstudios.dialywomensselfdefense.R;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference {
    private Calendar calendar;
    private TimePicker picker = null;

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt) {
        this(ctxt, null);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(ctxt, attrs, android.R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(ctxt, attrs, defStyle);

        setPositiveButtonText(R.string.set);
        setNegativeButtonText(R.string.cancel);
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        picker = new TimePicker(getContext());
        return (picker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        picker.setCurrentHour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        picker.setCurrentMinute(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, picker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, picker.getCurrentMinute());

            setSummary(getSummary());
            if (callChangeListener(calendar.getTimeInMillis())) {
                persistLong(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                notifyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return (a.getString(index));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {

        if (restoreValue) {
            if (defaultValue == null) {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(getPersistedLong(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            } else {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(getPersistedString((String) defaultValue)) * 1000);
            }
        } else {
            if (defaultValue == null) {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            } else {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong((String) defaultValue) * 1000);
            }
        }
        setSummary(getSummary());
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getSummary() {
        if (calendar == null) {
            return null;
        }
        HomePage.alarmMethod(getContext());
        return DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getContext()).format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
    }
}
```

Here is the class I am calling the preference that seems to be changing on each device.

```
public static void alarmMethod(Context context) {
        //ALARM SECTION
        AlarmManager alarms ;
        Calendar alarmCalendar;

        SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        long longTime = (getPrefs.getLong("notifyTime", 18));
        long x = (getPrefs.getLong("notifyTime", 18));
        boolean alarmUse = getPrefs.getBoolean("notifyBox", true);

        System.out.println("The time is " + longTime);
        System.out.println("Hello " + System.currentTimeMillis());

        x /= 1000;
        x /= 60;
        int alarmTimeMinute = (int)x%60;
        x /= 60;

        int alarmTimeHour = (int)x%24-4;

        System.out.println(alarmTimeHour);

        System.out.println("Hours (24hr) UTC - " + (x%24-4));
        System.out.println("Hours (12hr) UTC - " + (x%12-4));

        alarms = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        alarmCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimeHour);
        alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimeMinute);

        Intent activate = new Intent(context, AlertDaily.class);

        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, activate, 0);

        long timeToAlarm = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

        System.out.println("Militime is " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println(timeToAlarm);

        if (alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis())
        {
            timeToAlarm += (24*60*60*1000);
        }

        if(alarmUse) {
            alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, timeToAlarm, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
        } else {
            alarms.cancel(alarmIntent);
            System.out.println("You have disabled the alarm.");
        }
    }
```

Any help as to why the TimePicker is giving me different values on the emulator than on the phone would be awesome.

Comment: check you phone and emulator timezones + current date? make sure they are same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same type of issue, (i.e) getting different Time values in 2 different devices. I have solved the Issue by declaring the GregorianCalendar with TimeZone and Locale.

GregorianCalendar calendar =  GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.US);

In this case try like this

```
public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(ctxt, attrs, defStyle);

        setPositiveButtonText(R.string.set);
        setNegativeButtonText(R.string.cancel);
    //    calendar = new GregorianCalendar();  Modify this line as below
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.US);
    }
```

refer the url : [Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH gives different results on two different devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276061/calendar-week-of-month-gives-different-results-on-two-different-devices)

Comment: the one who is downvoted, tell the reason. before downvoting read the necessity and rules for downvoting.